# Implementing Apple Pay with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, applepay, passkit, uiviewrepresentable

This is my first time working with PassKit and with SwiftUI on a big project. I'm trying to implement Apple Pay SwiftUI and since there isn't a native way to do so yet, I tried wrapped the PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController in UIViewControllerRepresentable, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it properly.

The view displays properly and seems to work when clicking on it to pay. I control showing the window by binding the view to an isPresentingApplePay bool (see below). The issues happen when the window should be dismissed. Tapping on the `cancel` button does not dismiss the view; sometimes it doesn't even call the paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish delegate function. The same thing happens *after* submitting the payment. Sometimes the didFinish delegate gets called but the view is not dismissed. I tried passing the binding variable isPresentingApplePay and setting it to *false* from the didFinish but it doesn't do anything. The only way to get the view to disappear is to tap on any part *outside* of the apple pay window.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is there anything I'm totally missing?

I get the apple pay window to show properly when pressing a button, by binding the view under an `if statement`

Here is my PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController wrapper:

```
import Foundation
import PassKit
import SwiftUI

struct ApplePayController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @Binding var purchase: Purchase
    @Binding var isPresenting: Bool

    let items: [PKPaymentSummaryItem]

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, context: Context) {

    }

    typealias UIViewControllerType = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController


    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) ->  PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController {
        let applePayManager = ApplePayManager(items: items)
        let apm = applePayManager.paymentViewController()!
        apm.delegate = context.coordinator
        return apm
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate  {
        var parent: ApplePayController

        init(_ parent: ApplePayController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.parent.isPresenting = false
                }
        }

        func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {
            print("did authorize payment")

        }

        func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerWillAuthorizePayment(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
            print("Will authorize payment")
        }
    }

    class ApplePayManager: NSObject {
        let currencyCode: String
        let countryCode: String
        let merchantID: String
        let paymentNetworks: [PKPaymentNetwork]
        let items: [PKPaymentSummaryItem]

        init(items: [PKPaymentSummaryItem],
               currencyCode: String = "USD",
               countryCode: String = "US",
               merchantID: String = "xxx.merchant.xxx",
               paymentNetworks: [PKPaymentNetwork] = [PKPaymentNetwork.amex, PKPaymentNetwork.masterCard, PKPaymentNetwork.visa]) {
            self.items = items
            self.currencyCode = currencyCode
            self.countryCode = countryCode
            self.merchantID = merchantID
            self.paymentNetworks = paymentNetworks
        }

        func paymentViewController() -> PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController? {
            if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: paymentNetworks) {
                let request = PKPaymentRequest()
                request.currencyCode = self.currencyCode
                request.countryCode = self.countryCode
                request.supportedNetworks = paymentNetworks
                request.merchantIdentifier = self.merchantID
                request.paymentSummaryItems = items
                request.merchantCapabilities = [.capabilityCredit, .capabilityDebit]
                return PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I show it in my UIView:

```
if isPresentingApplePay {
    ApplePayController(purchase: self.$currentOrder.purchase, isPresenting: $isPresentingApplePay, items: self.createOrder(with: self.currentOrder.purchase)).environmentObject(self.userData)
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to work it out myself...

Comment: I have not yet. I'm tackling this this week tho and I'll post back anything I find

Comment: @user2805119 Hi, did you figure out a native SwiftUI way?

Comment: For a demonstration of how to present an [Apple Pay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/apple_pay) button in your SwiftUI app, please download the [Fruta](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fruta_building_a_feature-rich_app_with_swiftui) sample code project. In particular, check out the file Fruta > Shared > Orders > PaymentButton.swift. - posted by Apple Documentation Engineer.

Comment: The Fruta app only wraps the UI button, but doesn't illustrated presenting/dismissing the authorization view or state management.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have faced similar problem then I have solved by using another approach not interfacing UIViewControllerRepresentable. Instead I created a separate class for handling Apple Pay like following

```
import PassKit

typealias PaymentCompletionHandler = (Bool) -> Void

class PaymentHandler: NSObject {

static let supportedNetworks: [PKPaymentNetwork] = [
    .amex,
    .masterCard,
    .visa
]

var paymentController: PKPaymentAuthorizationController?
var paymentSummaryItems = [PKPaymentSummaryItem]()
var paymentStatus = PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.failure
var completionHandler: PaymentCompletionHandler?

func startPayment(completion: @escaping PaymentCompletionHandler) {

    let amount = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Amount", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "8.88"), type: .final)
    let tax = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Tax", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "1.12"), type: .final)
    let total = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "ToTal", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "10.00"), type: .pending)

    paymentSummaryItems = [amount, tax, total];
    completionHandler = completion

    // Create our payment request
    let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = paymentSummaryItems
    paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.YOURDOMAIN.YOURAPPNAME"
    paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
    paymentRequest.countryCode = "US"
    paymentRequest.currencyCode = "USD"
    paymentRequest.requiredShippingContactFields = [.phoneNumber, .emailAddress]
    paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = PaymentHandler.supportedNetworks

    // Display our payment request
    paymentController = PKPaymentAuthorizationController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
    paymentController?.delegate = self
    paymentController?.present(completion: { (presented: Bool) in
        if presented {
            NSLog("Presented payment controller")
        } else {
            NSLog("Failed to present payment controller")
            self.completionHandler!(false)
         }
     })
  }
}

/*
    PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate conformance.
*/
extension PaymentHandler: PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

func paymentAuthorizationController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {

    // Perform some very basic validation on the provided contact information
    if payment.shippingContact?.emailAddress == nil || payment.shippingContact?.phoneNumber == nil {
        paymentStatus = .failure
    } else {
        // Here you would send the payment token to your server or payment provider to process
        // Once processed, return an appropriate status in the completion handler (success, failure, etc)
        paymentStatus = .success
    }

    completion(paymentStatus)
}

func paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController) {
    controller.dismiss {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.paymentStatus == .success {
                self.completionHandler!(true)
            } else {
                self.completionHandler!(false)
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

And used the following Button code for Apple Pay popup.

```
struct ContentView: View {

let paymentHandler = PaymentHandler()

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
            self.paymentHandler.startPayment { (success) in
                if success {
                    print("Success")
                } else {
                    print("Failed")
                }
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("PAY WITH  APPLE")
            .font(Font.custom("HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16))
            .padding(10)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}

}
```

Finally, It works fine

Comment: paymentController?.present(completion: doesn't seem to work, how is it possible that you don't need to pass the VC to present?

Comment: @DepartamentoB PKPaymentAuthorizationController is not a ViewController, so it works.

Comment: Thankyou so much, this was driving me mental!!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer by Taif is very good on the `PaymentHandler` side.

But to use the actual Apple Pay button, it sounds like you were running into the exact same problem I had! Basically, you have to put your `UIViewRepresentable` in a `ButtonStyle`, and then style a SwiftUI button with it. I'm not sure why this is true, but here's the code as it should work:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import PassKit

struct PaymentButton: View {
    let paymentHandler = PaymentHandler() //As defined by Taif

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // Using the code from Tarif!
            self.paymentHandler.startPayment { success in
                if success {
                    print("Success")
                } else {
                    print("Failed")
                }
            }
        }, label: { EmptyView() } )
            .buttonStyle(PaymentButtonStyle())
    }
}

struct PaymentButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        return PaymentButtonHelper()
    }
}  
    
struct PaymentButtonHelper: View {
    var body: some View {
        PaymentButtonRepresentable()
            .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 400)
            .frame(height: 60)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}

extension PaymentButtonHelper {
    struct PaymentButtonRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var button: PKPaymentButton {
        let button = PKPaymentButton(paymentButtonType: .buy, paymentButtonStyle: .black) /*customize here*/
        button.cornerRadius = 4.0 /* also customize here */
        return button
    }
     
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKPaymentButton {
        return button
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKPaymentButton, context: Context) { }
}
```

Then to use it, you would say

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        PaymentButton()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A version that works for presenting the `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` can be found here: [How to properly present PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController in a SwiftUI only project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62638416/how-to-properly-present-pkpaymentauthorizationviewcontroller-in-a-swiftui-only-p)

The wrapper I'm using looks as follows:

```swift
import PassKit
import SwiftUI

struct ApplePayWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController

    let request: PKPaymentRequest

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController {
        let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)
        return applePayController!
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, context: Context) {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```

I'm using a `ViewModel` to act as a `delegate`, you need to add this to the fields of the `struct` after `let request: PKPaymentRequest` and then set the delegate when you create the `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use `UIViewControllerRepresentable` or `UIKit` at all in SwiftUI. Use [`PKPaymentAuthorizationController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentauthorizationcontroller), NOT the [view controller version](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentauthorizationviewcontroller):

```
let request = PKPaymentRequest()
request.paymentSummaryItems = ...

let controller = PKPaymentAuthorizationController(paymentRequest: request)
controller.delegate = self

controller.present { [weak self] presented in
   // Apple Pay presented from scene window
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649662?answerId=641228022#641228022